# Spring Boot remote shell fails when deploying to Tomcat

Tags: java, ssh, spring-boot, tomcat8

I'm using Spring Boot and I'm actually facing a (small) issue. It's really bugging me, and I haven't found an answer about it.

I've integrated `spring-boot-starter-remote-shell` in my pom.xml file. 
Everything is working fine when starting the application as a standalone Spring Boot app. But it doesn't work at all when I'm trying to deploy the war file to Tomcat using Eclipse Tomcat 8 plugin.

Here's the exception it throws to me :

```
2015-02-12 11:51:13.926 ERROR 1437 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.crsh.ssh.term.SSHLifeCycle           : Could not start CRaSSHD

java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.VMPCRandomGenerator"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:895)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2452)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1264)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
at org.apache.sshd.common.random.BouncyCastleRandom.<init>(BouncyCastleRandom.java:56)
at org.apache.sshd.common.random.BouncyCastleRandom$Factory.create(BouncyCastleRandom.java:48)
at org.apache.sshd.common.random.BouncyCastleRandom$Factory.create(BouncyCastleRandom.java:41)
at org.apache.sshd.common.random.SingletonRandomFactory.<init>(SingletonRandomFactory.java:37)
at org.apache.sshd.SshServer.setUpDefaultServer(SshServer.java:454)
at org.crsh.ssh.term.SSHLifeCycle.init(SSHLifeCycle.java:136)
at org.crsh.ssh.SSHPlugin.init(SSHPlugin.java:194)
at org.crsh.plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins(PluginManager.java:83)
at org.crsh.plugin.PluginContext.start(PluginContext.java:327)
at org.crsh.plugin.PluginLifeCycle.start(PluginLifeCycle.java:104)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration$CrshBootstrapBean.init(CrshAutoConfiguration.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:143)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5185)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a way to make it work (while keeping security of course) ?

Comment: Does your Tomcat container have bouncy castle in the parent classloader (someone would have had to add it I think)?

Comment: There is a `bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar` file in my deployment `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Note that it works like a charm when using `mvn spring-boot:run`. It's only when deploying the same war file to Tomcat that triggers this exception

Comment: In `WEB-INF/lib` is fine. The exception suggests that another version is also on the classpath in a different classloader.

Comment: It's a plain fresh install of Tomcat, I don't think it's included.

Comment: I guess maybe one of your other jars in `WEB-INF/lib` contains classes in `org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng` then. It shouldn't take long to figure out which one if that's the problem.

Comment: You were right. iText PDF library also needed an older dependency to bcprov. I removed it from the maven dependencies and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess maybe one of your other jars in `WEB-INF/lib` contains classes in `org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng`. It shouldn't take long to figure out which one if that's the problem